# Oracle update with join in execute update jsp

Tags: java, oracle, jsp

I want to update column1 of table1 by checking the condition with column2 of table1 and column2 of table2.

I just get the error of missing right parenthesis.

I just check the ID of both tables (ID is foreign key to another table) and check the activation code came from query string and if they match I just update the value of status as approve

```
String s = "Approve";
stmt.executeUpdate("UPDATE  
                                   ( SELECT Approval.STATUS AS st 
                                       FROM Approval 
                                       JOIN Activity 
                                         ON Activity.userid = Approval.id 
                                      WHERE Activity.activationcode = 
                                           '"+activationcode+"') as up SET up.st = '"+s+"'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your update table string with below and it should work

```
UPDATE 
 (SELECT 
    Approval.STATUS AS st 
  FROM 
    Approval JOIN Activity ON Activity.userid = Approval.id 
  WHERE 
    Activity.activationcode = '"+activationcode+"'
 ) up
SET up.st = '"+s+"'
```

In your query you are trying to update **APPROVAL and UP** tables both that is why you are getting an error

Comment: Can you post the error stack trace? This query should work so I am not sure why it does not work for you. Try to replace variables with hard coded values just for testing purposes and write a simple update statement.

Comment: I tried this query in Oracle command line, it works fine there. but when I execute this query in jsp it gives an error like:00907 missing right parenthesis

Comment: Are you sure that you are not concatenating anything with this query on your JSP page except you posted above? You can try to write a simple statement like `update approval set status = '1' where userid = '123'` and see if that works from your JSP page

Comment: yes.. there is nothing more I added. yes, it is working when I put custom values